# Add own function to ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, std, fstream

I would like to have my own class that work exactly like ifstream in any case but I can easily get the size of a file.

here is header:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class ifile: public ifstream {

    size_t _file_size = 0;
    size_t calculate_file_size();
public:
    ifile(): ifstream(), _file_size(0) {}
    ifile(const char *filename, ios_base::open_mode mode = ios_base::in):
        ifstream(filename, mode)
    {
        _file_size = cal_file_size();
    }
    size_t get_file_size();
    virtual ~ifile();
};
```

I have found many many information that I should not inherit from ifstream. How then I can easy resolve my problem then?

#### Edit:

calculate_file_size:

```
size_t ifile::calculate_file_size()
{
    auto present_pos = tellg();
    seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    auto file_size = tellg();
    seekg(present_pos);
    return file_size;
}
```

1. It would be nice to see proper example (if I can inherit from `ifstream`).
2. The reason is to calculate once and read many times.
3. Why not `get_file_size(ifstream &ifs)`? My ifstream obj is static this is so it's calculated many times.

Comment: Making `get_file_size(ifstream& ifs)` is always an option, right?

Comment: As a bonus it will work seamlessly, when uniform function calling makes it into the language.

Comment: You could write a wrapper class, which holds an `ifstream` and grants direct access to it. Then you can provide the functionality you need in that wrapper.

Comment: I don't know what "information that I should not inherit from ifstream" says, but there's nothing wrong with subclassing `std::ifstream`. But like with everything else, this must be done correctly.

Comment: Interesting reading: [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not allways, I want calculate once at read many times. 
@ RadosławCybulski I would like ifile work with streams just have additional function.
@ muXXmit2X Don't you think this is to much work for so much effect? 
@ SamVarshavchik I don't know too, it's reason why I am asking.
@ Niall How to subclass.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight or better yet, `get_file_size(istream& is)`.

Comment: @S.R:  Historically, the same issue has always existed with FILE.  This is probably due to the fact that some streams may not have a length at all.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy filestream can not have length at all? I will probably use get_file_size and store in static variable. But I am curious about it. Can u give me example or link about stream without len (it can bo on priv to not create offtopic)?

Comment: That is not what I said.  I said some types of streams do not have length. Remember that since files can be opened in sharing mode, the generic code must assume the file size can change at any moment. As for size-less streams: the main feature of streams is that they are interchangeable. A network or communication device connection can be described as a stream (a file HANDLE on Windows...) File streams are only a small subset of the streams "family"... std::fstream is often implemented as a wrapper around a FILE object, which is itself a stream - and FILE has no length function either,

Comment: You should avoid to derive from existing STD classes to add extra members. Make free function for that purpose or utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to inherit from `ifstream` to add new methods, here is a [code sample](https://github.com/gerbilvis/gerbil/blob/94f704447b5ce2dcd77019a641d96382dcb174a7/core/multi_img/multi_img_io_ext.cpp#L40) that never failed me on any platform. However as I understand it the `std` classes typically do not have virtual destructors, which you need to be aware of when handling the derived objects. So deriving from them creates new possibilities to make mistakes.

Comment: It's not accurate to say that "`std` classes do not have virtual destructors". To name just one, `std::basic_streambuf` has. Also, "adding member variables" is not relevant. If a base class doesn't have a virtual destructor, don't delete objects of derived type through a pointer to that base class. That rule does not depend on the contents of either type.

Comment: @MSalters so apart from this very reasonable rule, are there possible adverse effects to delete a derived type object without member variables and without a custom destructor through a pointer to the base class?

Comment: given that it's Undefined Behavior, the adverse affects may include nasal demons. In practice, it depends on the exact difference between base and derived class. The C++ committee failed to find a set of workable rules to define when it would be safe. Given just `struct Base { }` and `struct Derived : Base { }`, deleting a `Derived` object through a `Base*` is safe on normal compilers, certainly in release builds. But a workable rule would need to cover non-trivial cases.